# Change Magento's base URL

Tags: url, magento

I just moved my Magento installation to another URL (only updating apache config to use shop.domain.com instead of www.domain.com), and according to [this site](https://docs.nexcess.net/article/how-to-change-magento-base-urls.html), I just have to update some records in the database.

That works fine, except that all JavaScript and CSS files are still referenced from the old URL. I switched caching off in my browser, so I shouldn't be seeing old HTML files.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that another step needed when changing the URL manually, is to clear the cache: http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/magento/202-magento-cache-management/how-to-clear-the-magento-cache#manually

I removed all files, and it works OK again.